# Left & Right Cosets of $A_{4}$ in $S_{4}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

So I'm looking through solutions for a practice problem in my modern algebra textbook that has me completely stumped.

> Let $S_{4}$ be the group of permutations of the set $\{ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 \}$, and let $A_{4}$ the subgroup of even permutations.
>
> (a)  Write down all the left cosets of $A_{4}$ in $S_{4}$.
>
> (b)  Write down all the right cosets of $A_{4}$ in $S_{4}$.

The answer I've found has $A_{4}$, $(12)A_{4}$ for part (a) and $A_{4}$,
$A_{4}(12)$, what has me confused because wouldnt say $(34)A_{4}$ be another left coset? in fact wouldnt I have $(23)A_{4}$ or $(13)(23)A_{4}$ also be another coset ?

I understand that the the index of $A_{4}$ with $S_{4}$ is $2$ so that means their should be $2$ cosets in total no? I 'm very confused..

Comment: Just check your calculations carefully. As you have noted, $[S_{4}:A_{4}] = 2$ which implies $A_{4} \triangleleft S_{4}$. If you still dont know what that means, basically, this says that there is two lateral cosets and are equals, I mean that any left coset is a right coset.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa Yes but why are the cosets what they are?

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ then the two cosets $aH$ and $bH$ are same iff $ab^{-1}\in H.$ So in your case cosets of $(34)$, $(23)$, $(12)$ are same and the coset of $(13)(23)$ is $A_4.$

Comment: ah I see, so the permutation I choose doesn't matter? in other words $( 1 2 3) A_{4} = (1 2) A_{4} $ right?

Comment: wrong, (123)=(13)(12) and (12)^{-1}=(12) so (123)(12)=(13) is not an element of $A_4$ In fact (123)A_4=A_4